# How can I exclude androidTest tests from a particular package from compilation?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to configure my Android build to exclude specific androidTest tests (from a particular package) from compilation. This is because those tests won't compile under certain conditions. To make things simpler, as a first step I'm trying to exclude those tests always, and once I can get that working I'll try to adjust the logic of when they're excluded (based on specific properties).

Here's what I've tried:

```
android {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java {
                exclude '**/my/package/root/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
android {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.filter.excludes = ["**/my/package/root/**"]
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
android {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.excludes ["**/my/package/root/**"]
        }
    }
}
```

None of these work - when running `gradlew clean connectedAndroidTest` I always get multiple compilation errors of the form:

`e: file:///C:/nma/Repositories/myrepo/app/src/androidTest/java/my/package/root/others/ExampleTest.kt:986:19 Unresolved reference: SomeClass`

These compilation errors are expected (and the reason why I'm trying to exclude these classes from compilation) - my point is that the class was not excluded from compilation, regardless of what I put in the `sourceSets`. So I think my syntax may still be wrong - what should it be?